# What to do with question 'Running Tor on strange Wifi'?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

At the beginning of August [NoOne](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/3328/noone)
asked [Running Tor on strange Wifi](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3734/88). This question was later put in the [review queue](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/2427) as low quality post. At the moment I'm also quite unhappy with the question, but unsure if it should really be closed. What do you think here? Can we improve the question? Should it be closed?

Comments/discussion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unlike most questions of that variety - not *stellar* by any sense, but it contains enough information to make it objectively answerable, even if the majority of folks feel as if the answer should be rather obvious.

If it got a good answer, there's no real harm in keeping it around. Just some things to consider:

- Edit where you see the opportunity to do so. It's not always possible to make something like that less 'meh', but sometimes you can.
- Don't let 'meh' questions block much better ones that touch on the same topic, just in a better way. In other words, the older can be marked a duplicate of the newer, where warranted, and the questions merged.

There will always be questions that are just .. profoundly uninteresting :) And if you find yourself seeing a lot of this variety, then it's time to have a discussion about what they might have in common that folks are reacting negatively to, which could lead to adding a new close reason.

Until then, if it's seemingly on-topic and answerable, just answer (and edit) as you feel inclined.